# Connecting Aurelia with backend API

Tags: rest, http, express, aurelia

Context: I'm starting a new project for my company. It's been many years since I've done some web development and decided to build it using the latest platforms (so I'm a still new to all of this).

Current stack:

- Aurelia frontend (running on localhost:9000)
- Backend REST API using ExpressJS (running on localhost:8000)
- PostGreSQL database running on AWS, providing data for the backend

Question: I can't seem to connect my frontend with my backend properly.

Here is my code:

```
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import {HttpClient} from "aurelia-http-client";

@inject(HttpClient)
export class Login {

    constructor(httpClient){
        this.http = httpClient;
    }

    signIn() {

      const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/user/demo/test';

      this.http
            .get(url)
            .then(data => {
                console.log("data");
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Error getting ' + url);
                console.log(error);
            });
   };

}
```

This always end up in the catch block, with a "response: ProgressEvent"

If I put the url in the browser I get a proper JSON:

```
{"status":"success","data":[],"message":"Retrieved ALL users"}
```

The code above only works for 'local' content, i.e. localhost:9000. As soon as I need content from somewhere else I get this error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that CORS is not allowing you to access `localhost:8000` from `localhost:9000`. To solve this, you should enable your ExpressJS server to accept CORS requests from `localhost:9000` (or all hosts using a wildcard "*").

Look into these resources:

- https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html
- https://github.com/expressjs/cors
- Or search Google for 'expressJS cors'.

Comment: Solved! I looked at the first link and added this to my express backend: app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:9000");
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
 next();
});